# TemplateDoesNotExist at / index.html - URL Dispatcher Issues in Django

Tags: python, django

Attempting to create a simple application using Django 2.1.4.

Project name is "inventory_management", application inside the project is called "gInventory".

Here is tree view of my file management:

```
|   db.sqlite3
|   manage.py
|   tree.txt
|   
+---gInventory
|   |   admin.py
|   |   apps.py
|   |   models.py
|   |   tests.py
|   |   urls.py
|   |   views.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   
|   +---migrations
|   |       __init__.py
|   |       
|   +---static
|   |   +---css
|   |   |       bootstrap-grid.css
|   |   |       bootstrap-grid.css.map
|   |   |       bootstrap-grid.min.css
|   |   |       bootstrap-grid.min.css.map
|   |   |       bootstrap-reboot.css
|   |   |       bootstrap-reboot.css.map
|   |   |       bootstrap-reboot.min.css
|   |   |       bootstrap-reboot.min.css.map
|   |   |       bootstrap.css
|   |   |       bootstrap.css.map
|   |   |       bootstrap.min.css
|   |   |       bootstrap.min.css.map
|   |   |       style.css
|   |   |       
|   |   \---js
|   |           bootstrap.bundle.js
|   |           bootstrap.bundle.js.map
|   |           bootstrap.bundle.min.js
|   |           bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map
|   |           bootstrap.js
|   |           bootstrap.js.map
|   |           bootstrap.min.js
|   |           bootstrap.min.js.map
|   |           
|   +---templates
|   |       base.html
|   |       index.html
|   |       
|   \---__pycache__
|           urls.cpython-37.pyc
|           views.cpython-37.pyc
|           __init__.cpython-37.pyc
|           
\---inventory_management
    |   settings.py
    |   urls.py
    |   wsgi.py
    |   __init__.py
    |   
    \---__pycache__
            settings.cpython-37.pyc
            urls.cpython-37.pyc
            wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
            __init__.cpython-37.pyc
```

Whenever I run my local server and try and pull up the webpage, I'm expecting index.html to show up. Instead, I'm getting an error stating "TemplateDoesNotExist at / index.html" - the template doesn't exist, however I believe that the path is valid.

Below that error is the attempts to load by Django:

```
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\ateox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\ateox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
```

urls.py -- inventory_management:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [ #define urls from apps
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('gInventory.urls'))
]
```

urls.py -- gInventory:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import index


urlpatterns =[
    url(r'^$', index, name = "index"),
]
```

settings.py -- inventory_management

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'thkot@lru9#uo1ub$wpa%u!+)t3lcee^0#f*h8c=imvz@^lq8c'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'inventory',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'inventory_management.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'inventory_management.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and lastly, views.py -- gInventory

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: `inventory` vs `gInventory` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Settings.py`, you need to put replace `DIRS` in your `TEMPLATES` with this code.

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

This defines you have your `template` folder at base directory of project.

**Convention that you should follow :**

- Create a folder named after your app inside `templates` folder and put your html inside it.

  ```
  +---templates/
  |            ginventory/
  |                      base.html
  |                      index.html
  ```
- In your `view` functions you give html address as:

  ```
  def index(request):
      return render(request, 'ginventory/index.html')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Move your template folder under `gInventory` directory

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it as official documentations suggested, follow these steps:

> Your project’s TEMPLATES setting describes how Django will load and
> render templates. The default settings file configures a
> DjangoTemplates backend whose APP_DIRS option is set to True. By
> convention DjangoTemplates looks for a “templates” subdirectory in
> each of the INSTALLED_APPS.

1. So check if your app name is present inside `INSTALLED_APPS` list. Then check inside `settings.py` and look for `TEMPLATES` then check if `'APP_DIRS': True`.
2. Your template file should be in this path: `myproject/myapp/templates/myapp/mypage.html` This is the way django looks for templates in every app.
3. Finally your views function should end with something like this:

   def index(request):

   ....

   return render(request, 'portal/index.html', context)